# Dynamic variable in a call execute-macro script in SAS

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I have a macro which will generate a data set with column prod and 12 more columns. I also have a table prodincl_fr that contains sample data set below.

```
Rownum prodcat
----------
1      L
2      L1
3      M
4      LM
...    ...
```

I wanted to make a do until loop that will call on the macro %runlimitsquery and use on the value of prodcat in every iteration.

I couldn't figure out how to code this one out in SAS. I am playing along the codes below. Note reccount=number of rows of prodincl_fr.

```
data _null_;
set prodincl_fr;
do until(rownum=reccount);
  prod=prodcat;
  call execute('%nrstr(%runlimitsquery(&prod))');
  output;
end;
run;
```

Hope you can help me. Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

- `reccount` is not a variable of the `prodincl_fr` dataset and therefore does not exist in the context of that datastep. That `do` statement therefore equates to `do until(rownum=.)`
- you are calling that loop for each record in your dataset. Thus, throughout iterations of that loop, the value of rownum will never change and will remain the value rownum in the current observation. Your `until` condition will never be met and your code will run forever.
- `&prod` is a reference to a macro variable. But when you write `prod=prodcat` in your `data` step, you create a data step variable, not a macro variable. Therefore `&prod` does not exist.
- even *if* the `prod` macro variable existed, it would not be resolved because the reference to it is enclosed in single quotes. SAS does not try to resolve macro code/references within single-quoted strings. You need to use double quotes.

That code would be *syntactically correct* like so:

```
data _null_;
set prodincl_fr nobs=reccount;
do i=1 to reccount;
  prod=prodcat;
  call execute('%runlimitsquery('||prod||');');
  output;
end;
run;
```

**HOWEVER**, what this would do if, let's say, `prodincl_fr` contained a thousand records is the following: your datastep would go to the first record of `prodincl_fr`, initiate the loop which would call your macro one thousand times with the same value for `prod` which would be the value of `prodcat` for the current record; it would then move on to the second record and call the macro another thousand times with that record's value of prodcat; and so forth until the thousandth record.

Because I do assume this is not what you are looking for and because a data step with a `set` statement implicitly iterates over all records, you can do away with the do loop and write your datastep like so:

```
data _null_;
set prodincl_fr;
call execute('%runlimitsquery('||prodcat||');');
run;
```

Comment: I would continue using a %nrstr() wrap around the macro invocation as was in the OP.  The stacks all the %runlimitsquery macro invocations to occur after the data step completes.  The || string concatenation is OK, but can leading to some wonky logging if the data set variable is real long. Consider using CATS() to concatenate numeric and character data. Finally, a macro invocation does not always require a trailing semi-colon.  Whether or not is dependent on what the macro does, the context of the invocation, the context of any side effect text emission and possibly the context of the runtime

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of codegen in known to be less than 64K characters, you can use SQL to prepare your macro invocations.  I find this style of codegen to be particularly clear to the reader.

```
%macro runlimitsquery(prodcat);
  %put &sysmacroname called with &=prodcat;
%mend;

data prodcats;
  input prodcat $ @@;
datalines;
auto boat home flood aux worker life
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select 
    cats('%runlimitsquery(',prodcat,')')
  into
    :invoker separated by ' '
  from
    prodcats
  ;
quit;

%put NOTE: invoker=%superq(invoker); * lets see what is going to be invoked (the codegen);

* invoke the codegen;
&invoker
```

Last part of log

```
134  %put NOTE: invoker=%superq(invoker); * lets see what is going to be invoked (the codegen);
NOTE: invoker=%runlimitsquery(auto) %runlimitsquery(boat) %runlimitsquery(home)
%runlimitsquery(flood) %runlimitsquery(aux) %runlimitsquery(worker) %runlimitsquery(life)
135
136  * invoke the codegen;
137  &invoker
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=auto
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=boat
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=home
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=flood
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=aux
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=worker
RUNLIMITSQUERY called with PRODCAT=life
```

If the codegen is going to exceed 64k characters you probably want to step back and rethink the what and how of the task at hand.

Comment: I will try this one too. Thank you, Richard!